# Iterate over columns of Pyspark dataframe and populate a new column based on a condition

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement where I have a bunch of email, name, and other customer info in a PySpark dataframe. All my email fields are masked except one and I want to get the name of that field in the new column that I generate.

```
def add_base_col(df):
    for name in df.schema.names:
        df1 = df.withColumn("is_base", F.when(df[name].like("%*%"), None).otherwise(name))

    return df1
```

I know the above code over writes the new field that I am creating and just gets me the last column name in the dataframe, so I am not really sure how to do it correctly.

```
Name    Email1     Email2      Email3       Email4        Phone     is_base
ABC     abc@g.com  a**@g.com   x*@edu.com   za**@fgh.com  123459684  Email1
XYZ     xy**@c.com mkfg@bc.com s**@sflh.edu hgu**@j.com   237623747  Email2
```

The other approach I found was this, but did not help me either

```
df.withColumn("is_base", 
    F.coalesce(*[F.when(~F.col(c).like('%*%'), c) for c in df.columns])
).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure at most one email is unmasked per row, then you can use array and then concat the array items with EMPTY:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, array, concat_ws, col

cols = [ c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('Email')]

df.withColumn('is_base', concat_ws('', array([ when(~col(c).rlike('\*'), c) for c in cols]))).show()            
+----+----------+-----------+------------+------------+---------+-------+
|Name|    Email1|     Email2|      Email3|      Email4|    Phone|is_base|
+----+----------+-----------+------------+------------+---------+-------+
| ABC| abc@g.com|  a**@g.com|  x*@edu.com|za**@fgh.com|123459684| Email1|
| XYZ|xy**@c.com|mkfg@bc.com|s**@sflh.edu| hgu**@j.com|237623747| Email2|
+----+----------+-----------+------------+------------+---------+-------+
```